# ios UIButton touch cancel

Tags: ios, uibutton

Is there a way to cancel a touch for a `UIButton`? I envision it as something like:

```
- (BOOL)shouldProcessTouch {
    return NO;
}
```

You know, a place where you can run logic and *cancel* the touch in certain scenarios. Any ideas?

** EDIT **

For those familiar with event based systems, I'm looking for the equivalent of:
`event.stopPropagation();`

Comment: Why not just check for a flag in the IBAction method (or whatever method is called when the button is pushed)?

Comment: @scordova88 I'm not sure what you mean or how to go about trying what you're saying. Would you elaborate in an answer for me? pretty please?

Comment: try: youButton.touchesCancelled([], with: nil)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most cases, a UIButton will call a method when touched.  It may look like this:

```
-(IBAction)submitButtonPressed:(id)sender{

    if(shouldRespond){
       //do things normally
    }
    else{
      return;  //do nothing

    }


}
```

In this example, shouldRespond is your flag.  You should set this flag based on whatever conditions you have.

edit: the flag is a BOOL

Answer (score -1):

Why not just putting button in disabled state?

```
button.enabled = NO;
```

Or, disable user interaction for it:

```
button.userInterationEnabled = NO;
```

Comment: ironically enough, this is how I had things thinking that I could catch touches to a disabled button, but apparently you cannot so I can't set the button disabled anymore :(

Comment: Are you trying to disable the button when it's touched, then re-enable it later?  I don't understand why you would want to catch touches on a disabled button.

Comment: @jsd some of the buttons are conditionally toggle-able.